# How to put a jar in mvnrepository.com?

Tags: maven-2

I created a small open source Java library [LinkSet](http://code.google.com/p/linkset/) and I'd like to put it into mvnrepository.com.

How to do it? 
There is nothing like "upload/log in/sign in" link on this website :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, `mvnrepository` is only linked to the [Maven 2 central repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2). This mean that it automatically retrieve new or updated libraries that are present in this repository.

In others words, your library must be present in the official repository to be listed in `mvnrepository` site.

*Edit*: The [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53444/tim) answer will help you to find the procedure dedicated to the upload of your library in the central repository.