# How to make artifacts searchable in https://mvnrepository.com/?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, nexus, nexus3

I have few clarifications regarding https://mvnrepository.com/. Using the above link, I could able to find the available artifacts in different public repositories. My requirement is, I have artifacts uploaded in my hosted nexus 3 repository and I would like to make those artifacts searchable in the mentioned maven search engine.

It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279057/how-to-put-a-jar-in-mvnrepository-com/2279155#2279155) that my library must be present in the official repository to be listed on mvnrepository site.  I would like to know do we have any other options to make artifacts hosted in my nexus 3 repository to be searchable on this [site](https://mvnrepository.com/.)?
Please share your suggestions.

Comment: I would say it's more important be visible in https://search.maven.org/ The question is why you have hosted the artifacts in our own repo? Publish them into central https://central.sonatype.org/ and you can search for them....

Comment: The artifacts we are using is for commercial purpose and we don't want to share a source / related links. Hence we planned to maintain own repo.

Comment: If you share a jar file in java it's easy to decompile the files...so publishing in Central does not really make sense... you should hold in your own instance and limit the access via credentials etc.